# Numpy implementation of conditional update

Tags: numpy

I have a 2d np array of values 0 and 1 called t. I have another 2d array initialized with random values called q. They are the same size. I want to update q so that in every place t is 0 q is changed to be -np.inf
I believe the below loops work

```
for i in range(0, np.shape(t)[0]):
        for j in range(0, np.shape(t)[1]):
            if t[i, j] == 0:
                q[i, j] = -np.inf
```

However I am wondering if there is a more efficient solution using numpy.

Comment: `q[t == 0] = -np.inf`?

Comment: Q = np.where(t==0, -np.inf, Q)? Is your version considered better?

Comment: Also why does Q = np.where(t==0, -np.inf, Q) prevent doing Q[s,a] = .... later on

Comment: The boolean indexing (`t == 0`) is more efficient and maybe easier to read, but unless you have huge arrays any approach should be fine, it's really up to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.isclose` would be a better way, e.g.

```
q[np.isclose(t, 0.0)] = np.NINF
```